# How do I calculate points that is on a premium tile?

Tags: python

I am doing a project that calculates the points of a word in Scrabble. I am having problems in what to do next to see if the word is on the premium tile. I did an array of the premium tiles which is like the scrabble board.

```
premium_tiles = np.array([['3','1','1','2','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','2','1','1','3'],
                     ['1','2','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','2','1'],
                     ['1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1'],
                     ['2','1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1','2'],
                     ['1','1','1','1','2','1','1','1','1','1','2','1','1','1','1'],
                     ['1','3','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','3','1'],
                     ['1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1'],
                     ['3','1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1','3'],
                     ['1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1'],
                     ['1','3','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','3','1'],
                     ['1','1','1','1','2','1','1','1','1','1','2','1','1','1','1'],
                     ['2','1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1','2'],
                     ['1','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','2','1','1','1','2','1','1'],
                     ['1','2','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','2','1'],
                     ['3','1','1','2','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','2','1','1','3']])
```

After doing this I tried to use `doubles = np.argwhere(premium_tiles == '2')` to find the coordinates of the two's (same for triple just change to '3'). Also, I tried to find the coordinates of the output array using `coordinate_tiles = np.argwhere(arr1 != '0')` this is my array of words btw [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzQ2B.png)

I could already get the points of each word like for example `EAGLE = 6
APPLE = 9` How do I calculate the points? The output that I want is like this since EAGLE = 6 but since G is on a premium tile which is on the 2. The points should be 1+1+(2X2)+1+1 = 8.

```
[['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' 'A' 'G' 'L' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' 'E' 'A' 'K' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'L' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']]
```

This the output after I use computer vision

Comment: How do you place the word?

Comment: Are you open to using numpy?

Comment: Yes Im using numpy

Comment: I already post the output after output of the Scrabble in array. How do I get it to count the points if it is in premium tile?

Comment: Can someone help please? I really need this for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When placing the word in I assume you have the location of the tiles, and the order of the word. So you should be able to use a for loop adding to a sum value, something like,

```
def wordscore(svp, evp, shp, ehp):
sum = 0
if(evp>svp):
    for num in range(svp,evp):
        sum += premium_tiles[num][shp]*letterscore(word, num)
 else:
    for num in range(shp,ehp):
        sum+= premium_tiles[svp][num]*letterscore(word, num)
return sum;
```

Comment: What do you mean order of the word? I can get the word in the array but I do not know the position of the word only the letters. This is for python so can you please help me.

Comment: the order of the word would be 7,5 7,6 7,7 7,8 7,9 for eagle in your example, and 7,6 8,6 9,6 10,6 11,6 for apple, and in scrabble words are always read from left to right, or top to bottom. So you should know where the first letter starts, and where the last letter ends based on what they played, and what's on the board. assign the lowest and highest of both vertical and horizontal positions to their own unique variables, and pass that information to a function resembling the code above which returns the value of sum, so you can add that to the score of the player who played it.

Comment: def wordscore( svp, evp, shp, ehp ):
   sum = 0;
   for num in range(svp, evp)
   sum+=...
   ...
   return sum;

I'm not great with python syntax I'm more of a c++ kind of guy, so I think that is more accurate to python

Comment: Oh, I see. I get the logic but I was hoping that you could help me in the code since Im still find it hard to code sorry.

Comment: no worries, if you could mark my answer as correct that would be excellent

Comment: what are these variable mean svp, evp, shp, ehp?

Comment: starting vertical point, ending vertical point, starting horizontal point, ending horizontal point

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll just check first if it's working anyway thank you!!